# Show character at position in a file

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I would like to print the character at a given position using only the command line. E.g.:

```
<command> 5
```

Would output `a` if the 5th char of that file was `a`.

Since I am dealing with big files, ideally this would be able to handle big files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
$ echo 12345 | sed 's/.\{4\}\(.\).*/\1/;q'
5
$ echo 1234ắ | sed 's/.\{4\}\(.\).*/\1/;q'
ắ
```

Note that `sed` will fail to produce output if you input contain invalid multi-byte characters in current locale. You can use `LC_ALL=C` if you work with single byte characters only.

With ASCII file, you can also use `dd`:

```
$ echo 12345 | dd bs=1 skip=4 count=1 2>/dev/null
5
```

Comment: Is there any solution that doesn't involve having to pipe the input? Otherwise it will be slow in bit files no?

Comment: @testTester: Just use your file as operand to the command `sed 's/.\{4\}\(.\).*/\1/;q' file`

Answer (score 18):

If you want the 5th byte, counting from 1:

```
dd ibs=1 skip=4 count=1
```

or

```
tail -c +5 | head -c 1
```

Note that `tail` counts from 1, so given a file containing `abcdefg`, this prints `e`.

`dd` and `tail -c` are in POSIX. `head -c` is common, but isn't in POSIX; it's in GNU coreutils, BusyBox, FreeBSD and NetBSd and  but not in OpenBSD or Solaris.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that in their current form, these commands won't do anything. You'll either need to add a filename parameter on to the commands or pipe input into them. e.g.: `cat file | tail -c +5 | head -c 1`

Comment: @rinogo Both commands read from standard input and write to standard output.

Comment: Indeed! My aim was to help those new to Unix understand how to get data into the commands.

Answer (score 2):

Or using (gnu)grep:

```
grep -zoP '.{4}\K.'   file
```

(`-z` was used to deal with `\n` before the 5th char)