# How to print a file starting from the nth char?

Tags: command-line, dd

[Show character at position in a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/276851/show-character-at-position-in-a-file)

The above page shows how to use dd to print the nth char in a file. Is there a way to print a file starting from the nth char? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `tail`, for example, from the 5th character onwards:

```
tail -c +5 FILE
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this for 5th character and the rest:

```
dd ibs=1 skip=4 if=file 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: `dd` works and it's what you asked