# How to determine the Number of records in a binary file that has fixed size records

Tags: bash, binary, size

I am trying to determine the number of records in a binary file. The size of the binary file is determined by `wc -c`.  The delimiter is unknown .the size of records is fixed. The exact size of each record is not known
i want to determine the number of records

Comment: Welcome to the site. Unfortunately, your question is not quite clear. It seems you only know the size of the file, but neither the record size (apart from that they are fixed-size) nor the number of records, and want to determine the number of records. This seems like an unsolvable problem. Also, you mention "this approach is chosen" - which one? The only approach you mention is that to determine the entire file size (for which there are other possibilities, too). Please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/593369/edit) your question to clarify.

Comment: If you don't know the record delimiter, it is impossible to know the size of the records, or the number of the records or even if there are any records.

Comment: Unfortunately the question is still not clear after your edit. Do you know the record size? If so, it would appear to be a trivial matter to determining the number of records, unless the file format has fixed (or even variable) overhead of unknown size - in which case the problem would still appear to be unsolvable without knowing the delimiter ...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it describes an unsolvable problem.

Comment: Evidence the file isn't a single record, please

Comment: Adding to what has already been said in comments: if you are asking how to _guess_ the length and number of fixed-length records in a file you know nothing about except for its size, and maybe what are the conditions to be met in order to _prove_ whether a guessed length is the right one, you should make it clear.

Comment: No-one has yet touched upon the unwarranted assumption that a fixed-length record needs record delimiters.  (-:

Comment: @JdeBP Quite so. In fact it is logically invalid to have a binary file with a character separator, because any random integer or double could contain 8 bits that mimic the separator. Saying the size of each record is not known even implies there are multiple types of record with differing lengths. Three ways of designating record size. (a) Specify they are all the same. (b) Start each with a specific length field. (c) Start each with a distinct record type. All three require an external specification which apparently got lost. Possibly can be reverse engineered from an od given enough effort.

Comment: **If** you have a program that will tell you if you get it correct, then you can use the files size and the knowledge of fixed size records, and of the fixed delimiter, to search for candidate answers.(I am assuming that every thing you said is correct, and you have no other information, except a program, that is quick to run, that will tell you if you if your answer is correct).

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing exact size of record (and delimiter) makes this problem unsolvable in terms of simple and elegant solution.

**MAJOR WARNING:**
It might be a hopeless situation because there might be no delimiter at all (if software writing to file knows record size, there is no need to separate records with delimiters) or entire file might be one record. Also in some cases there might be "escape character" before character considered as delimiter inside record (unlikely with fixed record size, but it  would make situation worse to analyse), but "it depends". In addition, binary file formats can have a "header" block before the actual records start, and you would need to know its size for this to work.

There is small hope however. Because of certainty of fixed size length of records, then - *assuming there is no header* - the size of file (got by `wc -c`) has to be the product of record size and number of records.

We might try brute force approach:

1. Find size of file with `wc -c` (lets name it `fileSize`)
2. Find factors of `fileSize`.
3. Find all of combinations of factors, so you get every possible number of records that would fit into file.
4. Check for character ending possible record size. If you find hypothetical number that has records ending in the same character you might consider that this is delimiter.

This is not 100% perfect, but should help a bit with further research on records and file.

#### EXAMPLE:

File contents:

```
abcxdefxabnxccdxdfaxaafx
```

1. file size: 24 bytes
2. Factors: `factors 24`: 2 2 2 3
3. Possible combinations:

   - 2 x 12 (two records 12 bytes each)
   - 3 x 8
   - 4 x 6
   - 6 x 4
   - 8 x 3
   - 12 x 2
4. For each of those possibilities above we got delimiter:

   - `x`
   - `x`
   - (different ones, so this case is not considered)
   - `x`
   - (different)
   - (different)
5. We might guess that `x` is delimiter and smallest possible record size is 4 characters which fits into situation.

This is only example. You should try different assumptions and if file is quite bit you might use another approach like finding out distance between  two same characters.

Comment: You've mixed up factors and factorials.

Comment: You may move the final remark about the possible absence of a record separator to the top, making it clear that the rest of your answer assumes that a record separator exists. Also, to work as such, the record separator could not appear anywhere else than in record-ending position; i.e. "... records ending in the same character, and you verify it doesn't appear anywhere else than the last position of each record ...".

Comment: @JdeBP: My (english is) bad. Thanks for pointing it out. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# read filename to var f from $1
f="$1"
# quit if file not found.
[ -f "$f" ] || { >&2 echo "File not found." ; exit 2; }
# total length of file (-1 to not count newline at the end of a file)
n=$(($(wc -c < "$f")-1))
# loop potential length of records, end at half total length of file.
for i in $(seq 1 $(awk -v n=$n 'BEGIN{print int((n/2)+0.5)-1}')); do
    # now read all delimiters regarding record length from a file
    # (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/276957/236063)
    # and `sort -u` to get only individual ones
    c=$(for ((j=i;j<n;j=j+i+1)); do printf '%s\n' $(dd ibs=1 skip=$j count=1 < "$f" 2>/dev/null); done | sort -u)
    # if we have exactly one individual delimiter, we're done and can print length of record and the delimiter and exit.
    if [ $(echo "$c" | wc -l) -eq 1 ]; then
        printf 'l=%s d=%s\n' "$i" "$c"
        exit 0
    fi
done
>&2 echo "No delimiter found".
exit 1
```

Content of `file`:

```
abc,def,ghi
```

Output:

```
$ ./script.sh file
l=3 d=,
```

Exit Codes:

```
 0 success, found delimiter and record length
 1 no delimiter found
10 file not found
```

Note: I think there is some more work to fix some issues, especially regarding newline characters ...