# How to determine the number of records in a binary file given the delimiter

Tags: bash, files, binary, size

I want to determine the number of records in a given binary file.
The delimiter of the file is taken as input from the user.the total  How may I proceed ?

Comment: This should probably have been posted as an edit to yesterday's question 593369.

Comment: Previous question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/593369/117549 should be edited as Paul said.

Comment: Maybe not: at least this time it is certain that there _is_ a delimiter which was not clear in the previous question ...

Comment: @AdminBee It is `asserted` there is a delimiter. Given the first integer in the binary file can have 4 bytes that could each be any value from 0x00 to 0xFF, this has to be a hypothetical situation unless we know precisely what type and range of binary values can and cannot occur.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant whether this situation is very realistic is a completely different question (and was in fact discussed in that different question), but for the problem _described here_, the OP clearly assumed there is a delimiter. I think this does make the post distinct from the other one in that this is now a solvable problem, whereas the other one wasn't. I only wanted to point out that I think the other one should remain unaltered for future "this problem is unsolvable as discussed there" reference.

Comment: @AdminBee Waiting for my answer to be accepted, then. The tr version is fast, and totally agnostic about "line length" for a binary file. The only issue is quoting the delimiter as octal if it is an obscure control character. The awk may not like a 20GB file with few of the specified delimiters, but it would allow a regex or multi-char delimiter. LC_ALL="C" would be a good idea for a binary file too.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant no problems there from my side; the only question remaining would be whether or not the last record in the file is also terminated with the delimiter - but that has to be answered by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

```
LC_ALL="C" awk -v RS="${Delim}" 'END { print NR; }' < filename
```

RS is the Record Separator, and is a Regular Expression, so getting it wrong (i.e. invalid regex) will fail the script.

LC_ALL="C" is a temporary export to avoid issues where the arbitrary byte value in a binary might be interpreted as UTF-8 encodings.

However, I am interested to understand how any specified delimiter is going to work in a binary file, where any single byte in every integer, float or double can range from 0x00 to 0xFF.

You could also just remove all bytes that are not the delimiter, and count the bytes that are left. In this case, Delim is not a pattern, but it can be a set of characters, which may need escaping as per the man page.

```
tr -cd "${Delim}" < filename | wc -c
```

NB that "set" in tr is not a multi-byte entry: "ab" tests for 'a' or 'b', never 'ab'.